# VB6 Syntax error

Tags: vb6

I have the following code in VB6

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

  Dim encryptedFileName As String
  Dim decrypToFileName As String

  encryptedFileName = "Some File Name"
  decrypToFileName = "Some Other File Name"

  Dim afileDecryptor As fileDecryptor
  afileDecryptor = New fileDecryptor
  afileDecryptor.Decrypt(encryptedFileName, decrypToFileName)      

End Sub
```

class FileDecryptor has the following Sub:

```
Public Sub Decrypt(ByVal fileNameToDecrypt As String, ByVal decrypToFileName As String)

End Sub
```

I keepp geting compiler errot, Expected:= on the line

```
afileDecryptor.Decrypt(encryptedFileName, decrypToFileName)
```

I have looked at the everything I can , and still don't understand what the problem is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Subs don't return anything so you shouldn't have the parentheses around it's parameters.

`afileDecryptor.Decrypt encryptedFileName, decrypToFileName`

Comment: If you are used to having parameters in parentheses, add **call** in front of the sub.  eg *call afileDecryptor.Decrypt(encryptedFilename, decrypToFilename)*